# $\sup$, $\limsup$ or else, what is the error here?

Tags: integration, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

I am studying Dirichlet's problem on the half superior plane with the book *Mesures, Intégration, Convolution et Transformée de Fourier des fonctions* from El Haj Laamri.

The problem is the following:

> We are looking for $u\in C^2(\mathbb R\times ]0,+\infty[)$ satisfying
>
> $$(\mathcal D)\quad \begin{cases} \displaystyle\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2}=0 \\ u(x,0)=f(x) \\ \displaystyle\sup_{y\geqslant 0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\vert{u(x,y)}\vert\mathrm d x=0 \end{cases}$$
>
> where $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$. We also assume that for all $y>0$ : $u(\cdot,y)$, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\cdot ,y)$, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(\cdot ,y)$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}(\cdot ,y)$ are integrables on $\mathbb R$.

Thanks to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162043/does-there-exist-a-function-satisfying-sup-int-vert-u-vert-0), I know that a function $u$ satisfying the third condition

$$\displaystyle\sup_{y\geqslant 0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\vert{u(x,y)}\vert\mathrm d x=0$$

must be null everywhere.

This is why I do not understand this condition.

Is there an error in the book?

Should it be:

- $\displaystyle\limsup_{y\geqslant 0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\vert{u(x,y)}\vert\mathrm d x=0$?
- $\displaystyle\sup_{y\geqslant 0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\vert{u(x,y)}\vert\mathrm d x<+\infty$?

Comment: My guess after seeing more of the context is that it should be lim sup. This would be a "zero boundary condition at infinity", which would make sense seeing it is given below the boundary condition at $y=0$, and this is a dirichlet problem, so the boundary at infinity should have presecribed values as well.